80 or 90ies Anime, something about a submarine and apocalypse?
I do not remember much, i was a child (24-18 years ago), but some images of somhow bizarre, alien worlds and a giant submarine are in my mind.
I cannot ask my dad as he is very bad with remembering movies...
the value of production appeared high, well drawn. not a cheap childrens cartoon, but more of an epic movie.
any suggestions welcome! maybe with screenshots of the submarine?

I am almost sure you're referring to the OVA Blue Submarine no. 6
Here (animeclick) you can find some more images
It is set in a post apocalyptic future where almost all the surface of the Earth was flooded.
Giant submarine: the titular Blue Submarine no.6, part of a fleet of submarines that must fight against the mutants created by Zorndike, the scientist who caused the flooding.
Alien worlds: int the series are shown the internal of the mutant submarines (basically an organic-mechanic setting, since they are basically whales), and also the base of Zorndike, with all the mutant creatures he created.
I watched it in the early 2000, so also the timing seems correct

i think you might be right, i will have to watch in order to confirm. I was assuming it is a whole movie my parents watched, but maybe it was 4 episodes...

There's also Space Carrier Blue Noah, an anime TV series from 1979-1980 that was dubbed and released in the West as Thundersub, though this might be too early.

This is so painful, I watched Sealab 2020 when I was a kid, when 2020 was the distant future. I'll have to look up this Blue submarine show now.
2020 did not live up to it's hype, btw.
